# Data Archival in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, archive, elasticsearch-curator

Can you help me with how to **Archive data** in Elastic search. That I don't know what is curator and data shrink. I am fresher to elastic search. from where I have to start studying and what all things I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic search is an fulltext index. You can use this technology to index some data to get fast an powerful access to you data.

But, it's an index.

I don't think, elastic search is the right place to archive data.
Especially not if the archive is to fulfill certain archival standards.
You can archive your data somewhere else and use elastic search to search over your archived data.

If I were you, I would use a specialized tool for storing and archiving data and index this data with Elasticsearch for powerful search.

Comment: I think they're asking how to archive data that is already in Elasticsearch

Comment: I'm using Elastic search for indexing only and can I use curator for archiving data, but my data is stored in Elastic search.

Comment: My recommendation is to extract the data from elastic search to put them into a data-archive outside elastic.

Comment: We want to archive data from 5years which is stored in Elastic search.

Answer (score 0):

you need to look at using [ILM](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html) for this, it's the replacement for curator and will handle it much cleaner